# How to implement the Plugin Architecture in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development, plugin-architecture

I want to implement a plugin architecture in Flutter Dart. The process will be as follows:
1. User downloads the app.
2. The user loads plugins from our site.
3. The apps look if the plugin implements an interface.
4. If the interface is implemented then load information and widgets from the plugin to the app.

I've implemented the same process in C# using compiled DLL loading in runtime but unable to find it for Flutter.

I've looked into some of the previous questions and resource available on the internet and the closest one I found was this, https://pub.dev/packages/plugins but the plugin is not supported in Dart 2 and deprecated

This was the code I implemented in C#.

```
            int i = 0;

            if (Directory.Exists("Plugins"))
            {
                dllFileNames = Directory.GetFiles("Plugins", "*.dll");

                ICollection<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(dllFileNames.Length);
                foreach (string dllFile in dllFileNames)
                {
                    AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllFile);
                    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(an);
                    assemblies.Add(assembly);
                }

                Type pluginType = typeof(IPlugin);
                List<Type> pluginTypes = new List<Type>();
                foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
                {
                    if (assembly != null)
                    {
                        Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
                        foreach (Type type in types)
                        {
                            if (type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            else if (pluginType.IsAssignableFrom(type))
                            {
                                pluginTypes.Add(type);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    i++;
                }

                ICollection<IPlugin> plugins = new List<IPlugin>(pluginTypes.Count);
                foreach (Type type in pluginTypes)
                {
                    IPlugin plugin = (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    plugin.Initiate();
                    plugins.Add(plugin);
                }

                return plugins;
            }

            return null;
```

Comment: Non Dart solutions might be https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lua or https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wasm haven't tried any of those tho. Or maybe even a webview 

Comment: Looks more complex but seems more powerful https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_liquidcore basically providing a NodeJS runtime.

Comment: any new solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not possible.

Part of the AOT compilation preparing your app for upload to the stores is a tree-shaking, removing everything that isn't needed by the current build.  So, anything your plugin would need to call is gone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. After going through your answer, I got back to the board and came up with a theoretical solution (as of now) to create a decent plugin architecture in Flutter.

Comment: @TeckFreak would you mind sharing the solution you came up with? This would be of great value to the community :-)

Comment: @DamianK.Bast I have kept this project on-hold for sometime and has not worked on that solution yet. But the base of the solution was to design the code in such a way which can prevent tree shaking and perform JIT.